# Differences between components and controls in ENYO

Tags: enyo

I want to know what are the exact differences between components and controls and also the significance of each in ENYO?

Answer (score 3):

`Control` descends from `Component`.  `Control` is a component that has a DOM node associated with it, in the simplest sense.  Controls have additional functions, events and properties that are useful for items that will be displayed within a page.  `Component` is the base that introduces the concept of the nested `components` block and allows a hierarchy.

You might want to start exploring the docs here:  http://enyojs.com/docs/